# Set place of each bar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is working code. It creates bars of specific length.

```
# creating the dataset
data = {'C':20, 'C++':15, 'Java':30,
        'Python':35}
courses = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
  
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
 
# creating the bar plot
plt.bar(courses, values, color ='maroon',
        width = 0.4)
 
plt.xlabel("Courses offered")
plt.ylabel("No. of students enrolled")
plt.title("Students enrolled in different courses")
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I need more options. In future I will create animation of these bars. They will move left and right. So I want to set place of bar on x axis.
How can I do it?

My desired result looks like this (when I set place by my own)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are looking for - setting each bar at a specific place in the x-axis, you need to use `set_x()` for each of the bars. You can get this using `container.get_children()` and then move it around.

Note that I have the data as a dataframe and added a column called `pos`. This will define the distance of each bar from x-axis - zero. Plot the bars, then use set_x() to move the bars and `plt.xlim()` and `plt.xticks()` to align the ticks and labels. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
# creating the dataset - Using dataframe and adding pos column for distance from zero
data = {'courses' : ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python'], 'values' : [20, 15, 30, 35], 'pos' : [2, 3, 5, 7]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
# creating the bar plot
plt.bar(df['courses'], df['values'], color ='maroon', width = 0.4)
plt.xlabel("Courses offered")
plt.ylabel("No. of students enrolled")
plt.title("Students enrolled in different courses")

## Set xlim from 0 to largest value plus 0.5 to show all bars
plt.xlim(0, df.pos.max()+0.5)

## Access each bar and set the position based on value in df.pos
for container in plt.gca().containers:
        for i, child in enumerate(container.get_children()):
            child.set_x(df.pos[i]-0.2) ## 0.2 as you set width=0.4

##Adjust ticks and ticklabels
plt.xticks(ticks=df.pos, labels=df.courses)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to *re-order* the keys of your dictionnary ?

```
d = {k: data[k] for k in ["Java", "C++", "Python", "C"]} # <-- re-ordered `data`
P = [3, 5, 8, 13] # <-- positions of each bar/x-tick
W = 1.5 # <-- width of the bars

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))

plt.bar(P, d.values(), color="maroon", width=W)

plt.xticks(P, d.keys())
plt.xlim(0, max(P) + W)
```

Output :

[image]